# How to update the visibility of widgets whose data is stored in firebase firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to show two lists whose data is updated from firebase firestore using stream builder. One list contains all the tasks and another list contains tasks with a field value "taskStatus" of true. Everything works fine, I wanted to add the functionality that when there's no data in the "completedTasks" list, the whole widget area should just become invisible by changing the state of the visible parameter in the visibility widget. Here's the code for changing the visibility based on snapshot data from firebase:

```
Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(
              stream: DatabaseService().getCompletedTasks(orderName),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Loading();
                }
                List<Task>? completedTasks = snapshot.data;
                return Opacity(
                  opacity: snapshot.data!.isEmpty ? 0 : 1,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "Completed Tasks",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                const SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            itemCount: completedTasks!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Dismissible(
                                background: Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  child: const Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.delete,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                secondaryBackground: Container(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  child: const Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.delete,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                onDismissed: (direction) {
                                  DatabaseService()
                                      .deleteTask(completedTasks[index].id);
                                  AwesomeNotifications().cancelSchedule(
                                      completedTasks[index].id);
                                },
                                child: Item(
                                  task: completedTasks[index],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
```

To make changes, I've to hot reload the app. So, how can I change it to update the visibility without hot reloading the app.

Complete Code for both lists:

```
body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(
              stream: DatabaseService().getTasks(orderName),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Loading();
                }
                List<Task>? tasks = snapshot.data;
                if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                  return StreamBuilder(
                    stream: DatabaseService().getUniqueIDs(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) =>
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 30, vertical: 40),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Tasks",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Great! You don't have any remaining tasks.",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Image(
                              image:
                              const AssetImage('assets/images/tasks.png'),
                              height: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .height * 0.3,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                  );
                }
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 30, vertical: 40),
                        child: Text(
                          "Tasks",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey[700],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          itemCount: tasks!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Dismissible(
                              background: Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                child: const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              secondaryBackground: Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                child: const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              onDismissed: (direction) {
                                DatabaseService()
                                    .deleteTask(tasks[index].id);
                                AwesomeNotifications()
                                    .cancelSchedule(tasks[index].id);
                              },
                              child: Item(
                                task: tasks[index],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(
              stream: DatabaseService().getCompletedTasks(orderName),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Loading();
                }
                List<Task>? completedTasks = snapshot.data;
                return snapshot.data!.isEmpty ? SizedBox.shrink() : Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "Completed Tasks",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey[700],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          itemCount: completedTasks!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Dismissible(
                              background: Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                child: const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              secondaryBackground: Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                child: const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              onDismissed: (direction) {
                                DatabaseService()
                                    .deleteTask(completedTasks[index].id);
                                AwesomeNotifications().cancelSchedule(
                                    completedTasks[index].id);
                              },
                              child: Item(
                                task: completedTasks[index],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],);
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: could you add a sample of full code please?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I've updated the question with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another parameter for that, do this:

```
retutn snapshot.data!.isEmpty ? SizedBox(): Column(
     children: [
       ...
      ],
)
```

or If you want just make it invisible, try this:

```
Opacity(
    opacity: snapshot.data!.isEmpty ? 0 : 1,
    child: Column(
       children: [
           ...
       ],
    ),
),
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, if it was helpful, please approve it so other people find it easier.

Comment: but there's a little bug with the app now, as we're using the SizedBox widget when there's no data in the snapshot and above that, I've another widget that occupies all the space, the SizedBox widget is causing RenderFlex overflowed on the bottom...It would be better if I could just make it invisible if there's no data instead of showing SizedBox ig

Comment: I've updated the code again... I wasn't showing the expanded widget which was wrapping the stream builder...the issue wasn't fixed after wrapping the column widget with the opacity widget...the issue is cuz of the expanded widget, right?

Comment: @FaseehHyder check my answer to solve the empty SizedBox issue

Comment: you haven't that overflow issue before?

Comment: I think the over flow issue is not related you my answer, your strategy to show those list has issue.

Comment: Yeah..ig, but back then I was making the whole `StreamBuilder`  disappear by wrapping the Expanded widget with the `Visibility` widget but that was causing the issue as defined in the question I've asked...but I'll try to figure this out @eamirho3ein thankx for helping out till now...ur answer was helpful too

Comment: glad to hear that, if you don't want to scroll those list seperatly, you can wrap your main column with singleChildScrollView then remove the expanded widgets and set shrinkwrap to true and physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics for both list views.

Comment: it works now...I've used a different approach but it does the same work as u said...

Answer (score 1):

No need to use empty `SizedBox()` when you want to hide or show a widget on a condition.
Instead of `SizedBox()` use `SizedBox.shrink()`, it'll taking as min space as possible and more optimized than using empty `SizedBox()`

```
return snapshot.data!.isEmpty ? SizedBox.shrink(): Column(
     children: [
       ...
      ],
)
```

Comment: still the same issue...I've uploaded complete code for both lists for better understanding in case I'm not able to explain everything

Comment: The issue is still there bcoz you wrapped your `StreamBuilder` with `Expanded` widget and you put a check when you're returning the widget from `StreamBuilder`.

The `Expanded` and `StreamBuilder` will gonna take space even if there's `SizedBox.shrink()`.

Try to wrap the `Column` with `Expanded` instead of `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: but I need `StreamBuilder` to listen for changes in the database from firestore firebase....

Comment: @FaseehHyder I'm just saying to wrap the `Column` with `Expanded` instead of `StreamBuilder`, not to remove `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: ohh I see, but the issue is solved now....thankx to you too